# REQUEST_URI rewrite incl. query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, request-uri

I have a WordPress plug-in and theme that are malforming a URL call to an external css file.  I will fix that later, but until then, I need to do a redirect so the css is getting served correctly.

REQUEST_URI contains the full path, so why doesn't this work?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/%22https:/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%22$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/"https:/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

*Note 1*: I have tried several combinations of escaping characters in the RewriteCond.  Nothing works.
*Note 2*: I am using flag [R,L] for testing, to prevent browser caching.  Will change to [R=301,L] later.
*Note 3*: I have tested to verify that the problem is with the RewriteCond, not the RewriteRule.

***UPDATE***:

OK, so this was a bad question and a dumb mistake.  Even though raw REQUEST_URI contains the query string, mod_rewrite specifically does not allow query string to be in REQUEST_URI for matching purposes.  Hence, QUERY_STRING instead.  I thought that it could be done either way.

I don't have a *true* query string in my REQUEST_URI -- I have the query string that is in a string that I wanted to match -- so that is why I didn't go to QUERY_STRING at the outset.  But mod_rewrite still sees the `?` as a typical query string start.

Sorry, guys.  I can handle it like this until I fix the underlying problem in WordPress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/%22https:/fonts.googleapis.com/css(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/"https:/fonts.googleapis.com/css(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

*With WordPress, always remember to put your rewrites above the WordPress rewrites.*